How to Prevent Image Loss in Documents/Images Directory During App Upgrade
I'm encountering an issue with my app's offline queue processing during upgrades. Here's the process I'm following:

I create a local directory inside Documents/Images/.
I add images to this Images folder, which need to be uploaded to the server.
If a user adds a form with images, I add those images to persisted storage for later processing.

The problem arises when the app is upgraded. The images stored in the Images directory are lost during the upgrade. This results in zero size file uploads when the queued items attempt to upload to the server after the upgrade.
Here is a brief description of the issue:

A form with images is submitted.
The app is immediately killed.
The app is upgraded to a new version.
Upon reopening, the images in the Documents/Images/ directory are missing.

Is there any way to resolve this issue and prevent image loss during app upgrades?
Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
